Impedance discontinuity between layers in DDR layout
I am currently doing a layout on a 10 layer board and finished laying out my MPU to DDR connections. I used SI software to run simulations and I uncovered in the impedance delay simulations that the CA connections experience an impedance discontinuity (Shown below).

This discontinuity is due to the 55 ohm controlled impedance on my top layer being 54.15 ohms and on the internal signal layer is 55.45 ohms. The datasheet for the MPU specifically states that all CA connections should be striplines, making the via from the top layer to the signal layer necessary. I know that this impedance discontinuity will cause reflections, but my question is are these reflections a cause for concern for SI? The only feasible way to get the impedances closer is by bumping down the width of the top layer trace from 4.5mil to 4.25mil which would leave me with a top layer impedance of 55.49 ohms and signal layer still at 55.45 ohms.

What DDR speed and technology are we talking about?

@Klas-Kenny LPDDR3 800MHz

These simulated values are not meaningful to such high precision. The real board will be somewhere in the vicinity, but the difference between reality and simulation is so large that those little steps may as well be numerical noise.

I would just follow the manufacturer's layout guide and not worry too much about relatively small discontinuities like this. Of course there will be reflections but these will probably be insignificant compared to other sources such as vias, the BGA fanout and manufacturing tolerances (that are also much harder to quantify...).
I have routed DDR3L memory on the STM32MP1x where the impedance requirement is 55Ω ± 10% (Source: AN5122). Your impedances are not even close to this limit. As long as you account for the propagation delay differences between the stripline / microstrip traces I don't think there will be an issue.
